# Check if .json file is empty and than delete it from a directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
start_date = datetime.date(2020, 7, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 9)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while start_date<= end_date:
        url = f'https://newweb.nepalstock.com.np/api/nots/nepse-data/today-price?sort=symbol&size=500&businessDate={start_date}'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
            data=json.loads(url.read().decode())
            contents = data['content']
            
        out_file = open(str(start_date) +".json", "w")
        json.dump(contents, out_file, indent = 6)
        out_file.close()
```

Now, I have many .json files in the directory. Some of them are empty **[  ]** (with two brackets).
I want to check if a file is empty and delete it.
How can i do that in python?
Please help.

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Please show us what u already tried and provide a [mre]

Comment: The file itself is not empty. It contains a valid JSON value. It just happens that the value may be an empty array. You won't know that until you have decoded the JSON.

Comment: and also do you want to include the whole sub directories for search?

Comment: basically i scrapped data to json file from a website iterating date. but on holidays the data is empty. like 2020-07-04.json has  [ ] brackets only. so i want to check those files and delete it.

Comment: json files have `{}` if im not wrong, inside maybe they have `[]` but if its empty, tht means only `{}` is present

Comment: you said _"I have many .json files in the directory"_ but here in the code, you are not referring to your directory but a website

Comment: the code saves the file in the current directory

Comment: So essentially you are trying to delete json files on a remote server?? For deleting, your rest api either needs to support delete resource operation or you will have to ssh to the server and delete it.. for ssh you can explore paramiko python library

Comment: Basically @UpendraShrestha no one can/wants to help you if you haven't at least tried to write some code that accomplishes your problem. We see how you save the file but not show us some code that solves the problem you're having. If you've tried and failed show us what you have tried to do and we can help guide you. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I have written a code, but im not sure if its what you want, it will check the directory for the json and check if there are `[]` and then it deletes the json if there is atleast one `[]`

Comment: Thanks cool cloud.. With your help i managed to delete by checking.

Comment: wait up, ill add an answer check if itll help you out

Answer (score 0):

```
 import requests
 import datetime
 import json
 start_date = datetime.date(2020, 7, 1)
 end_date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 9)

 url = f'https://newweb.nepalstock.com.np/api/nots/nepse-data/today-price? 
 sort=symbol&size=5&businessDate={start_date}'
 response = requests.get(url)
 data = response.json()
 if data:
    with open(str(start_date) +'.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
 start_date += delta
```